# How to remove last two bytes from file descriptor?

Tags: python

Currently I'm using low level [`os.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.write), `os.read` functions for reading, writing contents from and to a file descriptor.

```
os.write(fd, b'echo hi')
os.write(fd, b' && echo foo')
```

successfully written to fd now I want to remove last two bytes from the `fd`. But I don't know how to achieve.. And it seems like `os.read(fd, 2)` not working.. Does it remove the last 2 bytes from fd?

```
(child_pid, fd) = pty.fork()
```

actually I got the `fd` from `pty.fork()` which creates a child process.

Actually I'm getting input from user and writing to pty, and I don't want the user to write \q[enter], so when an user enters "enter btn", I have to check whether the last 2 bytes already written to `fd`  is not `\\` and `q`, if so then I have to remove the last 2 bytes from fd.

Is there some other way we can achieve this behaviour?

Partially I can achieve this behaviour is by making use of `collections.deque` with max length set to `2`.

so before writing a byte or a char to `fd`, I have to append the char into the defined `queue`. On before writing enter char (`\r`) to fd, I'll check the queue's 0th and 1st position is not `\\` and `q`. If yes, then I simply discard enter from writing to `fd` but note that `\q` already written to `fd`.

Comment: You're showing Python code -- why do you have the `bash` and `shell` tags?

Comment: Answering the question you pose in the text, vs the one you pose in the title: Immediately after your `write()`s, the current position in the file is at the end; relative to the end, there's nothing left to read.

Comment: Is there any way to retrict the psudo terminal to run only one command , say for ex. python. ie. I want to run only python interpreter on the psudo terminal. So, what I did was, after creating the `pty` fork, I ran `subprocess.run(['bash'])` on the child terminal and write `python` command to the `master_fd`. This opens up the python interpreter but on exit, it return back to bash (which I don't want to). If it does, then it should be a restricted bash shell. So I replaced the first cmd with `rbash` but it's not working.

Comment: If you want a shell to exit in the process of starting another command, `exec` that command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `exec` works for my case. Thanks..